# Зачем используется так называемое «авторское мы»? Для чего единственный автор называет себя во множественном числе?

Tags: значение-слов

> **МЫ**...
> 2. Употребляется вместо «я» в авторской речи (так наз. «авторское мы»). *Мы сказали в начале статьи, что видим в романе Гончарова знамение времени*. Добролюбов, Что такое обломовщина?
>
> *[Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой.]*

> **МЫ**...
> 2. Книжн. =Я (при назывании себя в авторской речи). *Мы сказали в начале доклада. Мы рассмотрели достоинства романа.*
>
> *[Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.]*

Исходя из определений «мы» = «я». Но тогда почему не писать просто «я», ведь автор же не монарх, чтоб называть себя «мы»?

В первом словаре даётся пример из статьи «Что такое обломовщина?» Добролюбова Н. А. В этой статье автор не один раз называет себя во множественном числе, например:

> Может показаться странным, что **мы** находим особенное богатство
> содержания в романе, в котором, по самому характеру героя, почти вовсе
> нет действия. Но **мы** надеемся объяснить свою мысль в продолжении
> статьи, главная цель которой и состоит в том, чтобы высказать
> несколько замечаний и выводов, на которые, по **нашему** мнению,
> необходимо наводит содержание романа Гончарова.

Автор говорит не *«я надеюсь объяснить свою мысль в продолжении статьи»*, а *«мы надеемся…»*, хотя он единственный автор.

Для чего используется такой приём?

Answer (score 2):

[**Об авторском «я» в академическом дискурсе**](https://bookonlime.ru/lecture/6-ob-avtorskom-ya-v-akademicheskom-diskurse-0) (Н. А. Кипиани)

> «Авторское мы» вместо «авторского я» – это яркое проявление одной из особенностей русского национального характера – скромности. Вот как комментирует употребление личных местоимений 1-го лица в научной речи М. Н. Кожина: «Авторское «мы» употребляется «для скромности», «Употребление местоимения *я* при глаголе-сказуемом ведёт к подчёркиванию личности говорящего, поэтому, чтобы избежать нескромности, обычно *я* опускают». В этом следует видеть определённое отношение русского человека к собственному *я*.
> <...>
> Понятие скромности имеет различные оттенки: например, отсутствие тщеславия или самомнения, а также нежелание выставлять напоказ свои заслуги, достоинства, иначе говоря, своё «я». Скромность – это черта характера, позволяющая сопоставлять своё собственное «я» с мнением окружающих.
> <...>
> О том, что русский не должен был «ячиться», выпячиваться и гордиться, говорит масса русских пословиц и поговорок о скромности <...> Одна из самых известных и часто звучащих сейчас пословиц – *Я – последняя буква алфавита,* с её помощью ставят на место собеседника, который слишком большое место отводит своей персоне.

Добавлю от себя. Тот, кто пишет, а затем публикует художественные произведения или результаты исследований, чаще всего не одинок в своих изысканиях. Он знает, что должен быть благодарен определённому кругу людей, так или иначе принимавших участие в его творчестве. Их материальная, интеллектуальная, моральная помощь и отражается в этом «мы».

И вот ещё: [**авторское мы**](https://syntax.academic.ru/20/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D1%8B) (acadimic.ru)

> Употребление местоимения *мы* вместо *я, ты* в научном, публицистическом стилях с целью:
> **1)** объединения адресанта и адресата;
> **2)** направления внимания адресата на предмет речи, тему исследования. *Мы* используется в профессиональной речи врачей, парикмахеров, портных, официантов и т. п.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ. Последние определения из словаря  Т. В. Жеребило, я находил, когда сам искал ответ, но не понял. Первое определение касается того случая, когда автор имеет в виду себя и читателей/слушателей. Например: «Сегодня мы изучим то-то и то-то…», т. е. мы = я + читатели/слушатели. Но в примере, который я привёл в вопросе, не этот случай. Второе определение про то, что «авторское мы» каким-то образом направляет внимание — мне не понятно. Как оно может направлять внимание?

Comment: Первое объяснение Н. А. Кипиани я раньше не встречал. Но мне кажется, что тут не дело в русском менталитете. Мне даже думается, что это было привнесено в русский язык из иностранных, как было привнесено якобы уважительное обращение во множественном числе «вы» к одному человеку, что произошло в основном под влиянием французского языка и не было изначально свойственно русскому языку. Обращение на «вы» уходит корнями к «королевскому мы», которое потом перешло на чиновников и дальше на обычных людей. И тут дело как раз в тщеславии, а не в скромности.

Comment: Не в пользу того, что дело в русском менталитете говорит ещё тот факт, что похожее использование есть в английском языке [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=we): _use by writers to establish an impersonal style is also from Old English; it was especially common 19c. in unsigned editorials, to suggest staff consensus, and was lampooned as such at least since 1853 (see wegotism)_. 1/2

Comment: Трудно перевести, но суть в том, что причина использования «мы» — создание безличного стиля и это было особенно распространено в 19 веке в неподписанных редакционных статьях, чтобы навести на мысль, что это мнение группы сотрудников; и  такое использование «мы» даже высмеивалось. Вряд ли скромность будет высмеиваться. 2/2

Comment: @Eagle Итак, по порядку. Информацию из словаря я привёл уже после ответа, как говорится, вдобавок, для более полной картины, чтобы показать, с какими целями еще используется "мы".  В примере из вопроса автор, конечно, имеет в виду себя и, вероятно, своих соратников (а может, музу). // Второй пункт из словаря я понимаю примерно так: например, когда врач, как с ребёнком, говорит, *мы сделаем укольчик, будем принимать по 3 таблетки*, а парикмахер или портной – *здесь мы укоротим, а тут нарастим*. Адресат в таких случаях не будет выполнять действия, специалист же направляет его внимание.

Comment: Аналогия с местоимением "вы", как мне кажется, в нашем случае совсем не подходит. // Статья Кипиани – это не столько об "авторском мы", сколько о различиях между западным и славянским типом культуры в лингвистическом поле. Материал показался мне довольно убедительным, с большим количеством ссылок на серьёзные исследования (есть список литературы). Там говорится о том, что англо-американская традиция письма – индивидуалистическая, и в текстах мы видим только "I" (да еще и большой буквы), а русская традиция – коллективистская.

Comment: В последние десятилетия и у нас есть тенденция к прямой передаче авторства. Ментальность, несмотря на её устойчивость, тоже может меняться...

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с двумя объяснениями, которые, в сущности, могут дополнять друг друга.

1. "Мы" используют в научных работах, а пишет эти работы не только их автор, но и научный руководитель, так что все рассуждения и выводы у них общие, в связи с чем в этой работе не может быть "я".
   Если шире, то научный руководитель ставит подпись под работой, и раз уж она опубликована, то каждый тезис находится и на совести научного руководителя тоже. Автор работы больше не несёт за неё личную ответственность. Собственно, если бы он писал "я", то никто бы не мог диктовать автору, что исправить в работе.
   Не исключено, что эта практика по привычке перекочевала в книжное дело в целом. Однако там "мы" можно объяснить присутствием редактора. Хотя редактор, если рассуждать справедливо, не берёт на себя ответственность за содержание работы. Если научный руководитель в значительной степени является участником и соавтором в исследовании, то редактор остаётся внешней силой, ответственной за грамматику и достоверность фактов, но не за мысль и идею.
2. "Мы" обобщает "я" автора и читателя. Говоря что-то вроде "а теперь мы посмотрим на культуру времён XIX династии", автор, конечно же, собирается смотреть на эту культуру вместе с читателем (такое "мы", конечно, не является объяснением случаев "мы считаем").

А вот высказывание Н. А. Кипиани о "скромности русского национального характера" выглядит просто нелепо. Как минимум, требуются результаты исследований национальных черт русских, на которые бы автор сослался, если он пытается основать на таком тезисе объяснение.